# jquery ajax callback not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

please helppp :/ 
I swear to GOD this things was working yesterday pretty well. Just broke today, dont know why.
but the done callback from $.ajax is not firing.

```
function check() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/statistics/setup-Table",
                    dataType : "json",
                    success: function(data){
                        alert("check "+data['total']);
                    }
                }).done(function(){
                    alert("done");
                }).fail(function(){
                    alert("fail");
                }).always(function(){
                    alert("always");
                });
            }
```

i only get one alert >> "check 24"

no alerts from done, fail or always pops up. even for the other $.ajax calls, callback functions are not getting fired.
The url is fine too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I hope you have gone through this excellent post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: I did , but seems like all looks fine in this code. i get a response of 200 OK as well

Comment: BS i say. that shouldn't be possible. Check your console, there's likely an error. such as jqXHR.done is not defined (in the event you somehow loaded a really old version of jquery)

Comment: Works as expected in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Tmw9w/

Comment: $.ajax is broken by design. Do yourself a favor and wrap it for example to Q.

Comment: Cant thank you enough kevin... 
the cdn i was using were old version. which i inserted today. that would literally be the last place i would have looked. Thanks much man .. :D .. i just updated, alls working smoooth now ...!! :D

Comment: Thank you all for the response ... :D old version was the issue

Comment: @Aman the `console` should ALWAYS be the first place to look at ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the version I was using of Jquery that messed things up. the CDN that is.
Kevin B - thank you much .that really helped. 
Thank you to all the rest as well who looked into it for me .
You guys r amazing, i love this community. i hope i can help back as well ..

later guys. :)